# Facebook Comments Plugin Disappeared

Tags: plugins, facebook-comments

I had my Comments Plugin installed in my page, it was working fine for two weeks, and out of nowhere it stop working, It completely disappeared from my page. I can't see it and neither 8 people I've asked. I'm using the XFBML code. Hope I didn't get banned, I've done nothing wrong...

Here is the web: www.chrissyler.com/primeramision.html

Could someone help please ? Is this happening a lot ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All facebook widgets suddenly stopped working](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10029051/all-facebook-widgets-suddenly-stopped-working)

Answer (score 2):

You can see here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chrissyler.com%2Fprimeramision.html

If you're using a modern browser you can see an error message (or two) in the javascript console.

You're missing the special DIV that goes into the BODY of the HTML.  `<div id="fb-root"></div>`.